# Wildcard subdomains on localhost using IIS7

Tags: iis, wildcard, subdomain

I'm running IIS 7 on Windows 7 and would like to setup wildcard subdomains to test out an ASP.NET multi-tenant application that uses the subdomain to identify the user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you're wanting user.domain.com and user2.domain.com to be answered by the ASP.NET app such that user or user2 ID the user?

Comment: @Taylor - Yes (15 characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update 2016*

IIS 10 in Windows 2016 supports [wildcard host headers](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support).

*Origin answer*

Unfortunately IIS 7 still doesn't support wildcard mappings for subdomains (or any part of the domain binding).

You have a few options:

- If you can ensure the site only receives traffic on one IP and you own/have dedicated access to the server, you can use DNS to "fake" out the behavior with a wildcard mapping and no host.  There is a great post on this at http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7
- Simply let the site respond to all traffic, or all traffic using a supported binding, and let ASP.NET handle the subdomain processing.  Basically everything hits IIS and ASP.NET, and then you use code for the sub-domain control.  Your APP is at the root, and the subdomains and simply used by the app to obtain the user info.
- Use some sort of traffic control/url-rewrite module to rewrite requests to user or user2.domain.com to just app.domain.com (or whatever) with some additional header (i.e. 'X-UserInfo') that contains the username, and your app handles the username that way

Comment: The link above is broken...do you know where I can read about this?

Comment: Well actually I had done exactly the same thing before but now as there are some other sites on my server I wasn't able to create a website without host name but assigning a dedicated ip solved the problem (this one I didn't know) Thanks a lot